# Import data with "createdAt" and preserve insertion order

Tags: postgresql, xata

In [xata](https://xata.io/), each table comes with `createdAt` and `updatedAt` baked in. However, I'd like to import my existing table, which already has this information and these exact columns.

In [their docs](https://xata.io/docs/sdk/insert), under "Creating records", it states that id's are generated for each new record, and that they're [..] globally sortable. *This means that sorting by the IDs you sort by the insertion order*.

This is great... except how do I guarantee insertion order with a data import?  This information is already present in my `createdAt` / `updatedAt` columns, but I cannot set these upon import and there's no way to instruct xata to "use" that info.

I understand that I can always sort by `createdAt`, but this is often problematic, esp. in conjunction w/ fulltext searches which have their own sort logic.

Comment: tables are by nature unsorted as you have already one or two column which sorts the data, you simply add a ORDER By o your queries which is also good as resultsets also are unsorted by nature

Comment: Why is this tagged with sql server? You are using a completely different DBMS.

Comment: At best guess, @SeanLange, because there is no [tag:xata] tag, and so the OP decided to tag something completely unrelated... /shrug And according to the linked website, it's powered by PostgreSQL..

Comment: Not possible, there is no order in the storage of the data. The order is set in your select statements, the ORDER BY

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question at first, probably because I don't know what Xata is. Are you asking how to import data in Xata in some specific order? I would expect that, whatever format it uses, it runs sequentially--there's little reason to shuffle data. Perhaps you can add more context about that.

Comment: Present the data to `xata` sorted by `createdAt`. I'm betting it would then insert them in that order and assign the `id`'s in that order also. It should be simple enough to run a test case to verify.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yeah thanks, that's what i'm trying. It's just very time consuming to do it for 100k entries

Comment: I have no idea what is possible in `xata`, but an alternative would be to just dump the data into a staging table and then do `insert into <end_table) select * from <staging_table> order by createdAt`.